Is it possible to uses large partial private key exposure to recover the ecdsa nonce?
There’s many algorithms for recovering the private key from nonce leakage but I’m not aware of any of them for recovering a nonce from a ecdsa signature.
In details, I know the higher order 120 bits of the secp256k1 private key are set to 0 and the nonce is generated securely. While this isn’t enough to apply Pollard Kangaroo, is it possible to leverage the signature data in order to lower the effort to be computed?
Because while the effort of recovering the private key without the nonce is withing the reach of state backed organization, it’s definitely well above the largest Pollard Kangaroo record on ECDLP which indeed targeted secp256k1.

This is similar to (but different from) this question only with 150 (formerly 190) changed to 120, and the leakage more specific, and in the private key rather than the nonce.

@fgrieu The idea is if it s possible to recover the private from a single signature, then it might be possible to do the same for the nonce.

please edit the question so it is self contained with all the assumptions

@kodlu Everything is already in the question.

I assume the public key is available (as public implies). If it was not, it's easy to recover within 1 bit from one (message, signature) pair using the ECDSA Public Key Recovery Operation; and it's fully recovered with two pairs.
There's no known way any amount of (message, signature) pairs with unbiased and not leaked nonce can help recovering the private key, or equivalently a nonce. If there was, it would be major news!

There are $256-120=136$ bits to recover in the private key, requiring in the order of $2^{136/2+2}=2^{70}$ point additions by Pollard's kangaroo/lambda (or more generally some parallel collision search). That's a lot, but in the realm of feasible with a big waste of resources.
For comparison, a full sep112r1 DLP was solved in 2009 in 6 month with 200 Playstation 3. The proposed problem is perhaps 8000 times harder.
Update: Even more relevant, a secp256k1 problem with $114$ bits to recover was solved in 2020 in 13 days using 256 NVIDIA Tesla V100 (source). The proposed problem is a mere 2000 times harder, so that's definitely in the realm of feasible. A comment states that a problem with $133$ leaked bit ($123$ bits to recover) stands unsolved after 3 years. I guess the necessary resources have not been wasted (at least, correctly).
I see no better method without additional input, like signatures with biased nonce, or side channel information like power traces.

That s my point. It s within the reach of a state backed very large organization but not an individual. It s well above the world largest computational ECDLP record which indeed targeted secp256k1. Hence why I m looking on how to use the signature to recover the nonce in order to simplify stuff.

The ECDLP contest where the world largest discrete logarithm was solved for contains a bounty for solving a private key with 133bits leakage on secp256k1. It wasn t solved in 3 years.

@user2284570: Interesting (negative) data point. Are you considering that the private key has some high order bits at 0 (as in the present question) and availability of a signature with somewhat biased nonce (e.g. some known or chosen high bits) as in your other question? If so, please edit the question to state that. Cryptography and crypto-se requires precise problem statements!

In my case the nonce is unbiased generated by openssl1.1 so it s fully secure (beside the private key). And in the contest I m talking about, yes, it s about the higher order 133 bits being set to 0. Check Jean Luc Pons on wikipedia.

please edit the question so it is self-contained.
